# Electric Potential Outside of Two Infinite Sheets of Opposite charge density

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, energy, potential-energy

If you have two infinite sheets of equal but opposite charge density, the electric field outside the sheets will be zero due to cancellation. This led me to initially think that the potential would also be zero on either side of the two sheets. However, this implies a discontinuity in the potential, which I have read is not possible. Then again, if the potential is a certain constant on one side of the two sheets, and a different constant on the other side of the two sheets, the potential can be made continuous. Furthermore, the gradient of a constant is just zero, so such an expression implies zero E on either side of the plates, which is correct. Is my thinking here correct, and is the correct way to express the potential due to the plates to assign different constant potentials to the two sides of the plates? In general, how to we discern potentials across discontinuous points in an E field?

Comment: Your reasoning is correct, but I don't understand the question in the last sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are thinking of this in the right way with a constant potential on each side of the sheets. However, if we recall how we define the potential,$$V_\text{ab}=-\int_a^b\vec E\cdot\vec{dl},$$ we can see that a discontinuity in $\vec E$ does not give a discontinuity in $V$ (because integration never does), but instead gives a point where $V$ is not differentiable, and $\textit{this}$ is what corresponds to a discontinuity in the electric field. If you carry out the integration, you'll find that $V$ is constant on one side, then linear between the plates, then again constant on the other side.

It's also useful to remember that we only get to decide where the potential is zero, and the rest is decided by the above integral.